# How to lock orientation of e-book

Tags: css, orientation, device, epub, landscape-portrait

I am creating an e-book to read on a device (iPad, phone, etc.) and I want the e-book to always show the same orientation whether the device is rotating or in a landscape or portrait orientation.

Inside my code I have:

```
<p>
    name="viewport" content="width=595,height=842"
</p>
```

And in the .css file:

```
<p>
    height:770px;
    left:36px;
    position:absolute;
    top:36px;
    width:523px;
</p>
```

But my e-book keeps rotating and ignores the height or width I gave to the page.
Maybe I need another line or another setting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, the lock orientation is based on your devices. You can only style your ebook to be pretty on portrait mode, not lock orientation of the mobile at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this across all devices, but in the off chance that you're making a fixed-layout book for Apple devices, you can add some metadata in the `opf` file to lock orientation for those books:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  ...
  <meta property="ibooks:version">3.0</meta>
  <meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>
  <meta property="rendition:orientation">auto</meta>
  ...
</metadata>
```

The accepted values in the `meta` tag with the `rendition:orientation` property are `portrait`, `landscape`, and `auto` (or `none`? Docs are confusing a bit here).